# Docker (Ubuntu 16.04) Apache/PHP7/Mysql5_7 - Database: Connection failed: Connection refused

Tags: php, database, connection, docker-compose

Im trying to setup docker-container: Apache/PHP7/Mysql 5.7 via docker-compose up on Ubuntu 16.04.

The Problem is that i get no database-connection from the index.php  (localhost:8080).
If i try to connect it says: "Connection failed: Connection refused".

apache-php7 dockerfile: https://github.com/nimmis/docker-apache-php7/blob/master/Dockerfile

The Folders are:

apache-php7 (including Dockerfile)

html (including index.php)

mysql (mysql data)

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    build: apache_php7
    container_name: apache_php7
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_5_7
    volumes:
     - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
     - MYSQL_USER=admin
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test     
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
```

index.php (php-snippet)

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "admin";
$password = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

i searched for similar Threads and tried this also with PHP-PDO etc. -  nothing did work.

I'm able to log into the mysql-container manually via Terminal with the command:
docker exec -it  bash ,
and login via "mysql -u root -p " -> passwort: test.

Comment: Do you have something running locally (like, a MySQL instance) that's listening on port 3306?

Comment: I don't think you shouldt be using 127.0.0.1, run `docker inspect db | grep IPAddress` and use that address in your connect.

Comment: No, there are no local Databases installed, i would do everything with docker.

if i run the docker inspect command (after running docker-compose up), it says: 
"Error: No such object: db"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its solved.
First i get the name/id of the running mysql Container via

```
docker ps
```

and then i got a ip-address from the command

```
docker inspect <name of container> | grep IPAddress
```

like in this screenshot.

[command from nigel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nKfv.png)

I also modified this line in my docker-compose.yml:

```
    volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Thanks to Nigel Ren and thanks to jcorry for answering. Now everything is working.